# SwiftUI: Any way to place a view in a Navigation Bar on watchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, swiftui-navigationview

Is there anyway currently to place a SwiftUI View in a Navigation Bar in WatchOS? I want to put the TimeLineView duration counter from [Build a workout app for Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/build_a_workout_app_for_apple_watch) into the nav bar but can't figure out a way to do it especially given there are no tool bar items on watchOS.

My app currently puts it into the Nav Bar but only using a string via .navigationTitle but this prevents me from supporting Always On, i.e. the counter stops when the wrist down

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Apple has an initializer for navigationTitle that takes a view!

```
.navigationTitle {
    MyCustomView()
}
```